# How do I print a page that shows the various options for the different portions of a form?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I am using dropdown for various portions of a form.  I would like to print a page that shows the various options for the different portions of the form.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown only contains a limited number of list items, you should be able to get by with a screenshot.  Expand the droplist, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.  This will put an image of the current window in your clipboard.  You can then paste it into a program like Paint or Photoshop to crop to the piece you want.

If the dropdown has a scrollbar, you can take several screenshots at different positions in the list, then combine them together in Paint or Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I use the PrintKey utility to do this with more fexibility. It lets you capture parts of the screen, it can be set to capture/hide the cursor, etc.

I still use the free PrintKey2000 version (works well under Win7) that is no longer supported. The latest version, [PrintKey-Pro](http://download.cnet.com/PrintKey-Pro/3000-2191_4-10820437.html) is $19.95, with a 30 day free trial.